# onActivityResult is calling without finish of called activity for result

Tags: android, android-intent

In my code i am calling the application uninstall intent by the code :

```
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
uninstallIntent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
uninstallIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
startActivityForResult(uninstallIntent,DELETE_APP);
```

and in my activity i have overridden the method onActivityResult() but without any action on uninstall Intent is coming inside the method redundantly .

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d("", "request Code "+requestCode+" Result Code "+resultCode+"   "+data);

    if(requestCode==DELETE_APP){
       Log.d("Inside"'"Inside Delete Application Result");

}   
}
```

How can i get rid of that and why this is happening.

I am testing it on Galaxy S having Android 2.2. Is it any Os level issue or problem with the uninstall intent.Plese Help!!

Comment: don't understand what's happening here. when is onactivityresult called ?

Comment: when the uninstall intent is calling at the same time onactivity result is also calling without any action on the uninstall intent .it was working fine previously.

Comment: it is called when you start the uninstall activity ? and the uninstall activity is started and stays that way ?

Comment: ya exactly @njzk2 but i dont know why this is happening ?

Comment: what says the logcat ? it is possible the activity you start starts another activity and finishes itself*

Comment: @njzk2 no because the request code i am getting is also DELETE_APP.

Comment: which is not in contradiction with my hypothesis. can you check the logs to see if another activity is started ? (and possibliy post the logs?)

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for the support the problem is resolved it was happening because the activity which is calling the uninstall intent registered as singleInstance in manifest but I am not getting exactly why this was happening .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the activity which is calling the uninstall Intent registered in manifest with

```
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

that is why the problem was occurring but anyone can explain why this happened.

and if it is like to prevent the another instance why only the Intent called second time  was creating the instance that also should not be created ??

Comment: it is stopped (because it was not) and restarted. that's why

Answer (score 1):

You must set the intent

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
```